# Question on Calculus - Rates of Change application

Tags: calculus

I want to solve this problem:

```
A spherical balloon is being inflated. 
Suppose the radius of the balloon is increasing at
a rate of 2 centimeters per second.

a. Express the radius r of the balloon as a function of time t.
b. Express the volume V of the balloon as a function of time t.
```

This is how I tried to go about solving it.

```
a.

dr/dt = 2. Therefore dr = 2dt. Integrating gives r=2t. Thus the function is r(t) = 2t.

b.

You want to find an equation relating volume and time in the form of v = f(t). 
You can do this by finding the integral of dV/dT. You know V = (4/3)*pi*r^3.
Differentiating with respect to t gives dV/dT = 4*pi*r^2*(dr/dt). You know dr/dt 
from above, and it is 2. So dV/dT = 8pi*r^2.
```

Now is the part I am unsure about.

```
I needed to have everything only in terms of t 
so I substituted r=2t into dV/dT = 8pi*r^2. This gives dV/dT = 32pi*t^2. 
Now you can integrate. dV = (32*pi)*(t^2)*dt. Thus V = (32*pi*t^3)/3. 

So V(t) = (32*pi*t^3)/3
```

Is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't have to go through all of that.  All you needed was that

$$V=\frac{4}{3} \pi r^3 = \frac{4}{3} \pi (2 t)^3 = \frac{32}{3} \pi t^3$$

That said, this all assumes that $r(0)=0$, which may or may not be the case.  if not, perhaps $r(t) = 2 t+r_0$, where $r_0$ is given.